# Not able to register JavaTimeModule

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-time, fasterxml, jackson-modules

I have a spring boot application with version 2.7.3.

I have a util class, that creates a new Object mapper and registers the Javatimemodule class to that.

So in the test case, I try to verify that the registered module is added to the mapper.

This was completely working fine with my previous spring version 2.3. However when upgrading I see this strange issue.

Can some one help here ?

```
 static {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    }

  public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        return mapper;
    }


@Test
    public void returnsObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = Util.getObjectMapper();

        Set<Object> registeredModuleIds = objectMapper.getRegisteredModuleIds();
        assertThat(registeredModuleIds).contains(JavaTimeModule.class.getName());
    }
```

So when I run the test case with the higher version, I get the following error

> java.lang.AssertionError:  Expecting UnmodifiableSet:
> ["jackson-datatype-jsr310"] to contain:
> ["com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule"] but could not
> find the following element(s):
> ["com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule"]

Comment: Why? Why not utilize the one created by Spring or at least use the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` to get autodetection of modules. Nonetheless, this really feels like working around the framework. That being said your test (or assertion) is wrong, as it should test for the logical name of the module **not** the technical classname (as you can also see from the error message).

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, this error is appearing only after the upgrade of my spring version. However with the older version, I have not seen the error. Also, I would like to understand, what is then other way for me to assert that the Javatimemodule was then registered with the mapper

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the log, `ObjectMapper` actually has a required module registered in your test, but it's called "jackson-datatype-jsr310" instead of the class name.

AFAIK spring-boot of 2.7.3 uses Jackson version 2.13.3, where `JavaTimeModule`'s default constructor calls super constructor (of `SimpleModule` class) with a name "jackson-datatype-jsr310", and this name is returned by overridden `SimpleModule`'s `getTypeId()` method, which is stored then in the `ObjectMapper`'s `_registeredModuleIds` map.
This name is picked from the `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.PackageVersion` static `VERSION` variable, so if you want your test to pass try something like this:

```
@Test
public void returnsObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = Util.getObjectMapper();
    String javaTimeModuleName = PackageVersion.VERSION.getArtifactId();

    Set<Object> registeredModuleIds = objectMapper.getRegisteredModuleIds();
    assertThat(registeredModuleIds).contains(javaTimeModuleName);
}
```

Mind that exactly `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.PackageVersion` must be imported, because every `Jackson` package has this class.